# What does "my flesh begins crawling with suspense" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, quotes

The phrase was come upon in the following context:

> Show me a character whose life arouses my curiosity, and *my flesh
> begins crawling with suspense.*
>
> By Fawn M. Brodie (italics added)

Answer (score 2):

**make someone's [flesh/skin] crawl** - To cause someone's skin to feel funny or get goose pimples through fright.

- Source: McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs

**make one's flesh creep / make one's skin crawl** - Cause one to shudder with disgust or fear. *This idiom alludes to the feeling of having something crawl over one's body or skin.*

- Source: The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms

The author of your quote has apparently assumed artistic license to adopt and alter the normal meaning of this phrase, rendering it an alternative meaning correlated with suspense and curiosity, rather than fear or disgust.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the author is keenly interested in what's going to happen to the character in question. "Suspense" in this case means eager anticipation. The crawling flesh bit is almost, but not entirely, the equivalent of goosebumps.

Like, "Eeeee! What's this character going to do? What's he going to say next? Is he going to be successful? Less than successful? Is he going to marry that girl, or divorce his wife, or what? Eeeee, this is fun! My flesh is positively crawling ... with suspense!"

It's kind of corny, to be sure. But there it is.

Comment: If you say your flesh 'creeps' or 'crawls', it usually means that you feel disgusted or frightened. This author has chosen to use the idiom to describe the feeling of suspense.